# In crusader kings 2, what decides which titles I can revoke through plot?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

When you press pick ambition sometimes you get an ambition to revoke a title. This is a great way to reorganize your empire, without having to get claims on the title or incurring tyranny. But I can't figure out what decides which titles can be revoked through amibition. Anyone got a clue? So far I've ruled out:

1. Having a claim on the title.
2. Ruler desiring title.
3. Title was granted by ruler.
4. Holder of title doing traitorous stuff.

Comment: One factor: You need to have a negative opinion of someone to plot against them.

Comment: I don't think so. I can plot to revoke some titles I gave my heir, even though my opinion is positive.

Comment: I've noticed that when you have a duchy, you get plots to revoke the counties of that duchy.  ....except when you don't.  I have a two-county duchy, of which I own but one, but I can't revoke the other one through a plot.

Answer (score 9):

The "Revoke the County of ___" plot only requires that a count level vassal hold more than one county (or that a duke holds a county outside of his duchy) and that you not be incapable or an imbecile.  BUT meeting those requirements does not ensure that the plot will show up.  There is also an apparently random element in which plots appear and that random element is affected by a number of personality traits and other factors.  So a "Content" character is very unlikely to see this plot.  And a "Kind" or "Slow" character is somewhat unlikely to see it.  But an "Ambitious," "Decietful," "Envious" character who meets the basic requirements will almost certainly see it.  The chances of it appearing are also affected by your opinion of the target.  If you hate them (according to the game's calculation of your opinion) then it is more likely that you will have this plot available.

At least that is how I read the files.  I'd welcome anyone who has more insight into this.

Comment: I have available a plot to revoke a title from a count, despite him having only one single county of a two-county duchy (I have the capital).

Comment: Another possible reason for you to see the "Revoke County" plot is if the county is within your capital Duchy.

Comment: "(according to the game's calculation of your opinion)" – It always strikes me funny that the game calculates this. Like they know what we should think about every one of the simulated, puny rulers. There almost needs to be a diplomacy action for 'Actually, I really can't stand you.'

Comment: @Dacio because you aren't your character, [you are an alien entity mind-controlling it](http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v137/SelenaK/Fannish%20Stuff/LondoKeeper.jpg)… >:-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a strong claim on the county and be the liege lord of the count.  Then you can hatch a plot to revoke it.

But if you have strong claim and low (or no) +crown authority, you can revoke the title without tyranny penalty through the diplomacy menu.